# Split and replace Java string

Tags: java, string

I am trying to read a text file, split the contents as explained below, and append the split comments in to a Java List.

The error is in the splitting part.

Existing String:

```
a1(X1, UniqueVar1), a2(X2, UniqueVar1), a3(UniqueVar1, UniqueVar2)
```

Expected—to split them and append them to Java list:

```
a1(X1, UniqueVar1)
a2(X2, UniqueVar1)
a3(UniqueVar1, UniqueVar2)
```

Code:

```
subSplit = obj.split("\\), ");
for (String subObj: subSplit)
{
    System.out.println(subObj.trim());
}
```

Result:

```
a1(X1, UniqueVar1
a2(X2, UniqueVar1
...
```

Please suggest how to correct this.

Comment: Dude, use: str.split(", ");

Comment: The token around which is split won't get included in the result again. Solution would be to just reappend the token.

Comment: you are removing the ")," when you split/trim. Easiest way would be to append a closing bracket.

Comment: @user218046 that won't help. Consider "a1(X1, UniqueVar1), a2(X2, UniqueVar1)," this string would be split into "a1(X1", "UniqueVar1)", "a2(X2", "UniqueVar1)".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in your regular expression:

```
String[] subSplit = obj.split("(?<=\\)), ");
```

This expression matches a `,` preceded by a `)`, but because the lookbehind part `(?<=\\))` is non-capturing (zero-width), it doesn't get discarded as being part of the split separator.

More information about lookaround assertions and non-capturing groups can be found in the [javadoc of the `Pattern` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).

Comment: this is great. Could you please explain the split condition?